# Jenkins workspace folder permission

Tags: jenkins, nfs

This is my `jenkinx/jenkins_home/workspace` folder looks like. (while doing ls -la)

```
drwxrwxrwx 24 nfsnobody nfsnobody  4096 Sep 29 18:26 workspace
```

There is a folder inside this workspace. This folder was created by Jenkins automatically when i build a job. This job name is `Sandbox_Test-Job`

Here's the folder

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  4096 Sep 29 18:26 Sandbox_Test-Job
```

As you can see host machine's user does not have write permission to this folder and the script in the host machine is unable to write to  Sandbox_Test-Vinod_M

I will have to manually set the permission first for this folder before the script can write. How can we make sure that when Jenkins create this job folder for each job, the folder has to have write permission for the user in the host?

Comment: what is user `nfsnobody` in `/etc/passwd` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to run `ls -n` to find the *real* UID/GID of the files/dirs instead of the display names. Next, check to see if that user appears in your `/etc/passwd`

`nfsnobody:x:65534:65534:Anonymous NFS User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin`

You would need to find the displayed UID in `ls -n`, not `nfsnobody` - 65534.

It's unlikely "nfsbody is the owner of the files ( [RHEL NFS reference](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_nfs.html#nfs-volume-security) , [Linux Home Server HOWTO - Fedora](https://www.brennan.id.au/19-Network_File_System.html#nfs4) ), more likely the files were written to an nfs volume shared across systems where the UID for jenkins ( run `id jenkins`) is not the same across them.

Align the UIDs (non-trivial as you must fix the passwd plus the existing ownership UID) and things will then be OK.

Suggested [reading from SUSE](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017244) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/256200/linux-nfs4-permission-problem-with-owner-and-group).

If you're lucky - all the files have one UID and you just need to sync the UID in the passwds, or maybe blow them all away if it's just the workspaces.

ps: Not really a Jenkins issue, better guidance to be found on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

pps: there is some help on S/O worth reading as well (search "nfsnobody'):
[nfsnobody User Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825808/598141),
 [chown: invalid user: ‘nfsnobody’ in fedora 32 after install nfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416968/598141)